# Angular 4:match nested json item-value on event with the same item-value in other objects

Tags: json, angular, events, nested

I am working on an App with Angular 4.
I am a beginner with Angular.
I need help with 2 things:

-First: when I click on a user name in the HTML, I want to match the name clicked with the same user name in all the objects it is present in.

Second: display the title of the books this user name is present in.

For example: when I click on Jose Miguel I want to see, on the HTML, the 2 books he has read.

json data:

```
books = [
        {
            "title": "title1",
            "author": "author1",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Isidro"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Jose Miguel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Trinidad"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "title2",
            "author": "author2",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Jose Miguel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Beatriz"
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Rosario"
                }
            ]
        },
```

html:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <ul class="books">
    <li *ngFor="let book of books" >
        Título: {{book.title}} <br> Autor: {{book.author}}<br>
        <ul style="text-align:center" class="recentUsers">
            <li *ngFor="let user of book?.users" (mouseenter)="myEvent($event)" class="individualUsers">{{user.name}}</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Up to here I managed to display all books and the recent users that had read each particular book.

(mouseenter)="myEvent($event)" is only console logging, as you can predict, the name of the first user of the first book, but that is not what I need.
This is the part I need help with.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BooksService } from '../books.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-completo',
  templateUrl: './completo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./completo.component.css']
})
export class CompletoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private booksService: BooksService){

  }
  books = [];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.booksService.getBooks().subscribe(responseBooks => this.books =responseBooks);

  }
  myEvent(){
  console.log(this.books[0].users[0].name)
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter the book list in your event:

```ts
readBooks: Array;

// ...

showReadBooksForUser(userId: number) {
  readBooks = books.filter(
    (book) => book.users.findIndex((user) => user.id == userId) > -1
  );
}

resetReadBooks() {
  readBooks = null;
}
```

And maybe something like that in your HTML:

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <ul class="books">
    <li *ngFor="let book of books" >
        Título: {{book.title}} <br> Autor: {{book.author}}<br>
        <ul style="text-align:center" class="recentUsers">
            <li *ngFor="let user of book?.users" 
                (mouseenter)="showReadBooksForUser(user.id)" 
                (mouseleave)="resetReadBooks()"
                class="individualUsers">{{user.name}}</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- display book div with appropriate css? -->
  <div *ngIf="readBooks" id="readBooksOverlay">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let book of readBooks">{{book.title}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! 
I had to do some changes: 
readBooks: Array<string>;
showReadBooksForUser(userId: number) {
   this.readBooks = this.books.filter(
    (book) => book.users.findIndex((user) => user.id == userId) > -1);
  }

  resetReadBooks() {
    this.readBooks = null;
  }